# primefaces growl redisplays previous message

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a form which contains a list in a datatable. To add a New record to the list, click "Add" and the dialog box `<p:dialog>` appears, in that any empty datatable with 2 columns having two input text boxes to fill. In the dialog box I have Save and Cancel buttons. Once we click on Save button, a new record should saved into the database and the list in the form should show with the new record. The datatable is of primefaces inline row editing functionality. I'm using growl to display the error messages. Once I update my record with empty data, it shows the required message. But when I click on the Add button, it is again showing the same required message. It is showing the previous error. I don't want to have that. Could anyone help me in this context. The "Add" is an ajax request.

```
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/facelets/template/adminLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="view"> 
<h:form id="myForm" prependId="false">


<div class="header" >
    <div class="titleColor">
        T_COD_Prefil
    </div>
</div>

<div class="divPosition">
<p:dataTable var="profile" id="profileTable" value="#{profileView.profileModelList}" rowEditListener="#{profileView.rowEditListener}" onRowEditUpdate="buttonPanel" >
                    <p:column style="width:60px;">                  
                        <p:rowEditor/> 
                        <h:commandButton  style="padding-left:5px;" image="/resources/images/delete.jpeg" styleClass="spa"  value="delete" immediate="true" actionListener="#{profileView.delete}" >
                            <f:attribute name="delteProfile" value="#{profile}" />
                        </h:commandButton>                          
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>                                  
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="IDprefil" />
                        </f:facet>                          
                        <h:outputText value="#{profile.profileId}" />

                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>                  
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="description" />
                        </f:facet>                      
                        <p:cellEditor>                      
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{profile.profileDescription}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <h:inputText required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.desProfileEmpty}" maxlength="255"  value="#{profile.profileDescription}" />
                            </f:facet>                          
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>                 
                </p:dataTable>

        </div>
        <div class="divButPosition">

        <h:panelGroup id="buttonPanel">

            <p:commandButton id="buttons" value="Add" actionListener="#{profileView.addEmptyProfile}"
            async="true" update="myForm" rendered="#{!profileView.addNewRow}" oncomplete="profileDialog.show();" />

        </h:panelGroup>

    </div>

    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="false" />  
<p:dialog id="profileDialog" header="Profile Detail" prependId="false" widgetVar="profileDialog" resizable="false" width="500" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" modal="false" closable="false">

<h:dataTable var="newProfile" value="#{profileView.newProfile}">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="IDprefil" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{newProfile.profileId}" required="true" requiredMessage="not empty" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="description" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{newProfile.profileDescription}" required="true" requiredMessage="Desctiption should not be empty" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable> 
<p:commandButton value="Save"  actionListener="#{profileView.saveProfile}" async="true" update="growl,buttonPanel,profileTable" oncomplete="handleRequest(args ,document.getElementById('profileDialog'))" />
<p:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true" update="buttonPanel" async="true"  actionListener="#{profileView.cancelProfile}" oncomplete="profileDialog.hide();" />

</p:dialog> 
</h:form>
```

Comment: Please add the code of your page.

Comment: Hi Matt Handy, i placed my xhtml page

Answer (score 1):

Try writing your growl at the top of the code, and update it when clicking on the button.
Well, doesn't work on IE8.

Answer (score 0):

After submit button click, all fields will be validated first so, if some of them empty then requried message will be popup. So keep submit related data under different tag. Basically different forms for different submit buttons

Comment: could you elaborate on your answer.